# Number generator probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

A special calculator has a random number generator button which when pressed, displays a random digit 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. The button is pressed four times. Assuming that the numbers generated are independent of each other, find the probability of obtaining one '1', one '3' and two '4's in any order.

So in this question. The order doesn’t matter hence its combination instead of permutation however it involves repetition. I really need help understanding how to find the probability to this. I initially did it thinking order mattered and i got 12/625 but since they specified "in any order". How do i come about doing this?

Comment: You may find this of use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15884/permutation-with-duplicates

Comment: Your result of $\frac{12}{625}$ is correct.

Comment: @DanielMathias apparently its wrong. I was told that my solution takes order into account.

Comment: But you *do* have to take order into account, in the sense that you have to count 1134 and 1143 and 3114 and 3141 and .... Counting all the different orders, there are twelve of them each with probability $1/625$, so the answer is $12/625$, as you said.